# No Audio after installation

Tags: hardware, audio

I am having trouble getting my audio to work on elementary os after installation. It does work when I plug in my USB headset.

Also I am running os on CB35-B3340 Toshiba Chromebook 2 - Swanky.
Intel® Celeron® Processor N2840

Please let me know the commands you would like me to run in order to gather information to help troubleshoot the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the exact same thing as you running the cb2 and doing the native install for elementary OS with seaBIOS.

I also can not get my audio to work no matter what troubleshooting i do. You can try the troubleshooting procedures such as the one below, but be careful with just throwing commands in the terminal. The one in the link below has a big block of terminal commands that will install a ton of bloatware and the unity greeter- so dont run that command. But here is the link if you can get luck with it, let me know.
http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: While this link theoretically answer the question it is better to include the essential commands/steps in the answer =) After editing your post ping me with @Ravan in comment  , I will come and give you upvote :)